# How to provide options and control for Custom and complete installation in VS installer UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, installation, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have an Windows C# application for which I will have to create an installer 
which would ask user for custom and complete installation.These custom and complete installation options are same application with different feature.
I know to provide options by using Installer UI radio buttons but how to provide control as it takes specific exe for the custom and complete installation respectively.
Or is there any way to achieve this, appreciate if you would provdie step by step procedure.

I am using Visual studio 2013 premium version, MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

You have different ways, you can do it by configurate in VS. But on this I can´t say much. I would prefer to use a NSIS-File or MS-Build to create an setup.exe

With NSIS you can say all Options etc. which the installer should include.

[Here](http://%C2%B4http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Simple_tutorials) is an NSIS tutorial. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for custom dialogs in Visual Studio setup projects - they are limited feature setup projects that do not supply access to the full functionality of Windows Installer. Any installs you see with those Custom and Complete choices (or choices of which features to install) will not have been built with Visual Studio setup installer projects. That means you'll need to choose another tool that meets those requirements, and any others you might have for the install.

Comment: PhilDW, I learnt there are some options with 1)adding RadioButtons and setting conditions in the property window. 2) Writing Code in readme file under custom actions and adding it as dll. These two which are grey area as of now for me. I have two xml files namely CRS and CSS where I set target, if I choose CRS radio button the installer should select CRS xml rename the xml as original xml and copy and replace to a particular location. If this is done then my application would launch accordingly. Basically the target is read from XML.

Comment: "Custom" usually means you are shown a feature dialog where you can change the list of features to be installed - you won't get that with VS installer projects. You also can't go back and change your mind about what "features" are installed.  You didn't previously mention 'm not sure how readme and custom actions come into this because you didn't say exactly what you want to happen in custom and complete.

Comment: If not VS installer, is there any other open tools that would serve my purpose?

Comment: I use WiX installer which is very flexible.  The tool integrates well with Visual Studio.  Look here for more details - http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: Can I add Wix as Plugin to VS Premium 2013?

Comment: Punetth, look here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WiXToolset